# How do I resolve the operation not permitted error while attempting to install react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows

I'm running the latest version of Node.js, I have been using it for a few weeks now. So the next module in the web dev Bootcamp is to learn React. 
I used the suggested command: npx create-react-app my-app 
however, I got this error:

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\JIREHGIBSON'
command not found: create-react-app

Im using a windows PC, and did not have any issues using npm until when I tried to use react locally.

I have tried to install using a sudo line command, I have edited the configuration to get rid of the space in the user name, and i have tried a force command to clear the shell cache.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 way to resolve this:

```
npm cache clean
```

Or

Did a search for .npmrc file, and changed prefix= to the correct user.

Or

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Or

running cmd through administrator.

Comment: thanks so much! i thought I was running it as the admin, it's downloading as I type. I truly appreciate it!